# Raphael drop shadow effect

Tags: javascript, raphael, shadow

Does anyone know if Raphael supports the use of a drop shadow.  I am trying to create a drop shadow for an object I have created.  Here is the code I have, but I can't figure out how I would add a drop shadow.  Please help me if you can my manager is becoming VERY frustrated with me.

```
<html>
<head><title></title>
<script src="raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="draw-here-raphael" style="height: 200px; width: 400px;">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//all your javascript goes here

var r = new Raphael("draw-here-raphael"),

    // Store where the box is
    position = 'left',

    // Make our pink rectangle
    rect = r.rect(20, 20, 50, 50).attr({"fill": "#fbb"});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`.glow()`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.glow)-method can be used to some extent:

```
var circle = paper.circle(100,100,50);
var path = paper.path('m200,50 l100,0 l100,100 l0,100 z');

circle.glow();

path.attr({
    fill: 'blue'
});
path.glow({
    color: '#444',
    offsety: 20 
});​
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/sveinatle/gkayG/7/

<del>It seems to only work for the lines though, it doesn't actually fill the shadow.</del>

Comment: Well, simply set the fill property (to whatever value, doesn't matter, anything that's not falsy will do) and your glow()-produced drop-shadow is filled - http://jsfiddle.net/sveinatle/gkayG/3/

Comment: @rodneyrehm, Great, good to know, thanks! Will update the answer. You're link gives me a 404 though...

Comment: yeah, jsfiddle has been experiencing quite some issues lately. correct link: http://jsfiddle.net/gkayG/6/

Answer (score 1):

Raphaeljs does not have such functionality itself, but [plugins](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/raphaeljs) might help there. Also, for simple shapes I think the effect can be simulated by rendering it twice, first in black with partial transparency and a little offset (to imitate the shadow), and then the shape itself over it.

Comment: Is a plugin a function that someone else built that I can use by including it in the head?

Comment: this one is rather weird, but the guys [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/raphaeljs/S04MBOdf-v0/JxgIuE-24-8J) seem to have figured up how to use it

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I prefer to draw clones of the object beneath it, each a pixel removed from the previous, to get a 3D effect.

```
Raphael.el.depth = function(z, shade) {
    z = (typeof z !== "undefined") ? z : 5;
    shade = (typeof shade !== "undefined") ? shade : '#999';
    for (var c = 0; c < z; c += 1) {
        var s = this.clone().attr({ 'fill': shade }).transform("t" + (c + 1) + "," + (c + 1));
    }
    this.toFront();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an extension for handling this kind of thing. It's really easy to use:

```
circle.shadow();
```

would do what you want. Also, it's an implementation of SVG filter effects (which `glow()` isn't) so it will work with animations, etc.

The project page is here: http://chrismichaelscott.github.io/fraphael/.

Answer (score 0):

Another very good solution is to use `clone()` function. This is good alternative since it will work with complex `paths`. And it really looks like a shadow.

Check out the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ry8kT/128/)**:

```
var r = new Raphael(10,10, 500, 500);
var p = r.path("M100,300 L100,100 C100,100 250,100 250,300z");
p.attr({fill: 'yellow'});

p2 = p.clone();
p2.attr({fill:'gray', stroke:'none'}).transform('t7,5');

p.toFront();
```